# TextGraphiteMetricsSender: Error writing to Graphite: connect timed out While sending metrics from jmeter

Tags: jmeter, influxdb, grafana

I have my influxdb installed in one of the remote windows machine (UK machine). From my local machine(Indian) i'm trying send data to influxdb using a dummy script in jmeter with backend listener. For which im getting **"TextGraphiteMetricsSender: Error writing to Graphite: connect timed out"** error.

I'm able to send data(from my machine) to influxdb installed in any other windows machine which is there in the same network as mine.

I tried pinging the remote W.machine ,which is successful.And i'm able to send metrics from the same machine using jmeter with backend listner.

(FYI- Same influxdb setup i had in other remote windows machine (UK). for which i could able to send from my local machine.)

Now i'm getting **"TextGraphiteMetricsSender: Error writing to Graphite: connect timed out**" error in jmeter log.

How can i confirm if this issue is because of firewall.? How can i confirm the root cause. or how can i resolve this.?

Please can anyone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to verify the connectivity between machine where JMeter is running and the machine where InfluxDB is running using i.e. [telnet command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491013.aspx) (or equivalent) like:

```
telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 2003
```

Where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is IP address or hostname of the machine where InfluxDB is installed and `2003` is InfluxDB port (it should match [`bind-address`](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.9/administration/config/#bind-address-8088) setting in the `influxdb.conf` file)

Given telnet command is successful JMeter should be able to connect and send metrics, if not - you will need to open port `2003` in OS or router firewall.

See [Real Time Results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) JMeter user manual chapter[How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results) article for comprehensive step-by-step instructions on setting up JMeter and InfluxDB.

Comment: hi Dmitri T ..thanks for your quick response like always :)
yes i tried telnet ..its an firewall issue.Need to open port as you said.thanks